# Issue with upgrading sentry from 9.1 to 10

Tags: python, pip, sentry

I am trying to upgrade selfhosted Sentry from 9.1.2 to the latest 10.0, but unning *pip install --upgrade sentry* gives this :

```
  Collecting xmlsec>=0.6.0
  Using cached xmlsec-1.3.8.tar.gz (59 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/sentry/bin/python /usr/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpx4yHqi
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-X3YynY/xmlsec
  Complete output (10 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/usr/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 108, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      backend = _build_backend()
    File "/usr/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 99, in _build_backend
      obj = getattr(obj, path_part)
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__legacy__'
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/sentry/bin/python /usr/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpx4yHqi Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding `--no-use-pep517` in your `pip install`

```
pip install -U sentry --no-use-pep517
```

Refer this page: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/

Hope this will work !